# Timestamp for Ubuntu version update

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, version

How can you find the timestamp that Ubuntu updated versions, eg. upgraded from 20.04 to 20.04.1?

I have tried searching in the apt history logs located in `/var/log/apt`, however these logs contain information on specific packages being upgraded rather than the operating system version itself.

Is there a way I can get a timestamp on when it changed from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** (Following the comment from Stephen Kitt.)

You can look when the new version of `base-files` was installed. This package, among other things, updates files containing information about the current release. You can learn what version of the package to look up by consulting its changelog, which is linked at its page ([here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files) or [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/base-files)).

```
base-files (11ubuntu5.1) focal; urgency=medium

  * /etc/issue, /etc/issue.net, /etc/lsb-release, /etc/os-release: Bump
    version number to 20.04.1 in preparation of the next point release.
```

So, you can look when version `11ubuntu5.1` of `base-files` was installed to learn when your system upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1.

**Initial suggestion:**

The upgrade happened when the newer packages from Ubuntu 20.04.1 were installed. So you can look [Ubuntu 20.04.1 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/20.04.1) and pick a package to check. Then check that package's changelog to identify the version which had to be installed with the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1. Than you can `grep` through the log to learn when that version was installed.

For example, the Ubuntu 20.04.1 [release notes for `linux-firmware`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/20.04.1#Kernel_and_Hardware_support_updates) are:

> linux-firmware 1880792 Add sof-firmware and tplg files for tgl
> machines
>
> linux-firmware 1885970 Revert the sof-firmware and tplg files from
> v0.6_release for tgl machines
>
> linux-firmware 1886390 Fix an issue that HID devices are not scanned
> by Realtek 8822C
>
> linux-firmware 1887595 Integrate TGL_SOF_FW_prod_signed_v0.6.2_release
> for tigerlake machines

The [page of `linux-firmware` package for focal-updates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/linux-firmware) directs to [the changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.187.3/changelog) beginning with:

```
linux-firmware (1.187.3) focal; urgency=medium

  * alsa/sof: support 1 and 3 dmics (LP: #1891585)
    - SAUCE: sof-firmware: add 1ch and 3ch topology files

 -- Seth Forshee <seth.forshee@canonical.com>  Wed, 19 Aug 2020 13:17:13 -0500

linux-firmware (1.187.2) focal; urgency=medium

  * Revert the sof-firmware and tplg files from v0.6_release for tgl machines
    (LP: #1885970)
    - SAUCE: Revert "UBUNTU: SAUCE: add sof firmware and tplg for tgl platforms"

  * Fix an issue that HID devices are not scanned by Realtek 8822C
    (LP: #1886390)
    - rtl_bt: Update RTL8822C BT FW to 0x0999_3AA1

  * Integrate TGL_SOF_FW_prod_signed_v0.6.2_release for tigerlake machines
    (LP: #1887595)
    - SAUCE: integrate TGL_SOF_FW_prod_signed_v0.6.2_release

 -- Seth Forshee <seth.forshee@canonical.com>  Wed, 15 Jul 2020 08:11:59 -0500

linux-firmware (1.187.1) focal; urgency=medium

  * Add sof-firmware and tplg files for tgl machines (LP: #1880792)
    - SAUCE: add sof firmware and tplg for tgl platforms

 -- Seth Forshee <seth.forshee@canonical.com>  Wed, 17 Jun 2020 07:36:48 -0500
```

The last version of `linux-firmware`, which matches the Ubuntu 20.04.1 release notes is 1.187.2. So, looking when this version was installed should tell when the system upgraded.

Comment: Good suggestion; the best package to use for this is [`base-files`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files) which is always updated for a point release.